# Creating dense arrays without holes.

Tags: javascript

Sparse arrays:
Creating a sparse array of a given length is simple:

```
> var a = new Array(3);
> a
[ , ,  ]
> a.length
3
> a[0]
undefined
```

When you iterate over it, you can see that it has no elements. JavaScript skips the holes.

```
> a.forEach(function (x, i) { console.log(i+". "+x) });

> a.map(function (x, i) { return i })
[ , ,  ]
```

can we iterate over the elements, to fill the array with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (typeof a[i] === "undefined") {
        a[i] = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Depends on what you want to fill it with, but just replace "whatever" with the filler.